# Unable to connect to my Docker container running inside a single-node Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes newbie here.

First, let me tell you about the functionality of my Node.js sample application. It is a simple web server that responds with the text "Hello from Node" in response to a `GET` request to the root (/) route. Also, when the server starts, it outputs the text "Server listening on port 8000".

Currently, the app is running inside a container on a single-node Kubernetes cluster. (I am using Minikube)

When I run the command `kubectl logs web-server`, I get the desired response. `web-server` is the name of the running pod.

But when I try to connect to the application using the command `curl 192.168.59.100:31515`, I get the response: Connection refused. I should see the response: "Hello from node" instead.

Please see the picture below.

[image]

Please note that in the picture above,  `k` & `m` are aliases for `kubectl` & `minikube` respectively.

My YAML files are as follows:

node-server-pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: web-server
  labels:
    web: server
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web-server-container
      image: sundaray/node-server:v1
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

node-server-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-server-port
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3050
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 31515
  selector:
    web: server
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not see that your service targets 8000 of the app. Could you show the service spec?

Comment: @vladtkachuk Please note that the text ```server listening on port 8000``` is hard-coded. So, it does not matter. I am interested in ```nodePort``` which is ```31515```. I have added the YAML files in the question.

Comment: yeah, but your app is running on 8000 and your service tries to reach it at 3000

Comment: @vladtkachuk: Can you please take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73020343/how-can-i-publicly-access-my-application-running-on-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-amaz