# How can I publicly access my application running on a Kubernetes cluster on Amazon EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

Kubernetes & AWS EKS newbie here.

I have deployed a simple Node.js web application onto a cluster on Amazon EKS. When I send a `GET` request to the root (`/`) route, my app responds with the message: `Hello from Node`.

My Deployment and Service configuration files are as follows:

eks-sample-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eks-sample-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eks-sample-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eks-sample-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: eks-sample-app-container
          image: sundaray/node-server:v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
```

eks-sample-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eks-sample-app-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3050
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 31515
  selector:
    app: eks-sample-app
```

After I deployed my app, I checked the container log as shown below & I get the right response: `Server listening on port 8000`.

[image]

Now, I want to access my application from my browser. How do I get the URL address where I can access my app?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is Ingress

> An API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-access-kubernetes-services/

Comment: Can't I access my app using the NodePort service type?

Comment: not sure how it works in EKS, but I suppose it is possible. any reasons avoiding ingress?

Comment: I recommend you use EKS docs and tutorials, there seem to be quite a lot of info
https://www.stacksimplify.com/aws-eks/kubernetes-for-absolute-beginners/create-kubernetes-nodeport-service-manifest-with-yaml/